I am not being able to access my error response in Nextjs
I have my login method with nodejs and expressjs. How can I show my error response as a message in my nextjs component?
exports.login = asyncHandler(async(req, res, next) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;

    if(!email || !password){
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Please enter all fields' }] });
    }

    //Check if user exists
    let user = await User.findOne({ where: { email: email }});

    if(!user){
        return res.status(404).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'User not found' }] });
    }

    const isMatch = await user.matchPassword(password);
    if(!isMatch){
        return res.status(401).json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Invalid credentials' }] })
    }

    this.sendTokenResponse(user, 200, res);
})

For evey issue I return a response with a statuscode and a msg.
I want to access this response from my nextjs app when an error occurs while loggin in.
auth.service.ts
import { HttpAPI } from "../common/http.service";
export class AuthService {
    static async login(email: string, password: string, onUserLoaded: (user: any) => void) {
        try {
            const response = await HttpAPI.post('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/login', { email, password });
            localStorage.setItem('access-token', response.token);
            
            const userResponse = await HttpAPI.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/me', {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${response.token}`
                }
            });
            onUserLoaded(userResponse.data);
            document.cookie = "authenticated=true; path=/";
            console.log("Respondiendo con error")
            return response;
        } catch (err) {
            throw new Error(err.response.data.errors[0].msg);
        }
    }

    static async getUserProfile(token: string) {
        try {
            const response = await HttpAPI.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/auth/me', {
                headers: {
                    'Authorization': `Bearer ${token}`
                }
            });
            return response.data;
        } catch (error) {
            throw new Error('Error al obtener el perfil del usuario');
        }
    }
    


    static async logout(){
        localStorage.removeItem('access-token');
        function deleteCookie(name: string) {
            document.cookie = name + '=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
        }
        deleteCookie('authenticated');
    }
}

authContext.tsx
"use client"
import { AuthService } from "@/services/auth/auth.service";
import { UserType } from "@/types/user.types";
import { getAuthToken } from "@/utils/getAuthToken";
import { useEffect, useState, createContext, FC, PropsWithChildren, useContext } from "react";

export type AuthState = {
    authToken: string | null;
    user: UserType | null;
    authError: string | null;
    login: (email: string, password: string) => Promise<void>;
    logout: () => void;
}

export const AuthContext = createContext<AuthState | undefined>(undefined);

export const AuthProvider: FC<PropsWithChildren> = ({ children}: PropsWithChildren) => {
    const [authToken, setAuthToken] = useState<string | null>(null);
    const [ authError, setAuthError ] = useState(null)
    const [user, setUser] = useState<UserType | null>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const token = localStorage.getItem('access-token');
        if (token) {
            setAuthToken(token);
            AuthService.getUserProfile(token).then(userData => {
                setUser(userData);
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error('Error al obtener el perfil del usuario:', error);          
            });
        } else {
            setAuthToken(null);
            setUser(null);
        }
    
        const handleStorageChange = () => {
            const token = localStorage.getItem('access-token');
            if (token) {
                setAuthToken(token);
                
                AuthService.getUserProfile(token).then(userData => {
                    setUser(userData);
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.error('Error al obtener el perfil del usuario:', error);
                });
            } else {
                setAuthToken(null);
                setUser(null);
            }
        };
    
        window.addEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange);
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener('storage', handleStorageChange);
        };
    
    }, []);
    


    const login = async (email: string, password: string) => {
        try {
            await AuthService.login(email, password, async (userData) => {
                setUser(userData)
                const token = await getAuthToken();
                setAuthToken(token);
            });
        } catch (err) {
            setAuthError(err.message)
        }
    };
    

    const logout = () => {
        setAuthToken(null);
        setUser(null);
        AuthService.logout()
    };

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider value={{ authToken, user, login, logout, authError }}>
           {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
       );

    }
    
const useAuthContext = ():AuthState => {
    const context = useContext(AuthContext);
    if (!context) {
        throw new Error("useAuthContext must be used within an AuthProvider");
    }
    return context;
    }
   
export default useAuthContext;
           

http.service.ts
export class HttpAPI {
    public static async fetch(url: string, options: RequestInit): Promise<any> {
        const response = await fetch(url, options);
        if (!response.ok) {
            const errorData = await response.json();
            throw new Error(errorData.errors ? errorData.errors[0].msg : 'Network response was not ok');
        }
        return response.json();
    }

    public static async get(url: string, options?: RequestInit): Promise<any> {
        return this.fetch(url, { method: 'GET', ...options });
    }

    public static async post(url: string, body: object, accessToken?: string): Promise<any> {
        return this.fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(body),
        });
    }
}

So I am trying to catch the error message and set it into setAuthError for later rendering it from m authErrorCard.tsx
AuthErrorCard.tsx
"use client"
import Globe from "../svgs/Globe"

interface AuthErrorCardProps {
    errorMessage: string;
   }

export const AuthErrorCard = ({ errorMessage }: AuthErrorCardProps) => {

    if(!errorMessage) return null;

    return (
        <div className="flex items-start w-[400px] p-4 bg-[#ff4c3f26] gap-3 mb-6 rounded-[5px]">
            <Globe/>
            <div className="flex flex-col w-full h-full">
                <p className="text-white text-sm font-bold">Oops! There was and error when trying to login</p>
                <span className="text-xs text-[#E79F9F]">{errorMessage}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

LoginContainer.tsx
"use client"
import useAuthContext from "@/contexts/authContext";
import { AuthErrorCard } from "./AuthErrorCard";
import LoginForm from "./LoginForm";

export const LoginContainer = () => {

    const { authError } = useAuthContext();
    console.log(authError)

    return (
        <>
            {authError && <AuthErrorCard errorMessage={authError} />}
            <LoginForm/>   
        </>
    );
}

I am always getting either null or err.response is undefined, I had the idea that the issue was because in my api I was returning the error as a response and not as an error, but I´ve tried returning a new Error, but instead I was not able to access the error message.
